# How to set permission for an specific branch in github (in a public repository)?

Tags: git, github

Can I make a branch hidden for all, and show only for an specific group of users, in a public repository? The account is set as an Organization.

The situation is: There is a repository, and two branches: develop and release.
I'd like to hide the devel branch for the audience, and make it visible only for a group.

Can I do it?

Comment: See if this answers your questions.. If not, let us know.. http://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/

Comment: GitHub doesn't offer such a feature. To keep your branch private, you should not push it to GitHub (or keep it in a private GH repo).